# Missing module when using pyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a stand-alone program for macOS from a python script using pyInstaller however every time I try to run the program the pyInstaller creates, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Program.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'fpdf'
[18189] Failed to execute script Program logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Modules used:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import os
from fpdf import FPDF
```